# How can i retrieve the list as intended with only objects of type T?

Tags: c#

How can i retrieve the list as intended with only objects of type T?
T will always be a class derived from LevelActor

```
#Filter a list of only T from levelActors, T will always be a class derived from LevelActor
public List<T> GetActorsOfType<T>()
{
    List<T> matchingActors = new List<T>();
    foreach( LevelActor levelActor in levelActors )
    {
        if( levelActor is T )
        {
            matchingActors.Add( levelActor );
        }
    }
    return matchingActors;
}
```

Comment: Side note: If `T` is always derived from LevelActor, you should declare your method as follows to ensure this at compile time: `public List<T> GetActorsOfType<T>() where T : LevelActor { ... }`. That having been said, `Enumerable.OfType` exists, so you don't need your method anyways.

Comment: The linked duplicate post queries the difference between two methods, whereas this question asks about filtering a list.

Answer (score 2):

What you have looks broadly ok. If you want a more succinct solution that leverages LINQ, you can use the `OfType<TResult>()` method, docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netcore-3.1).

E.g.:

```
var filtered = levelActors.OfType<T>();
```

You can chain an extra call to `.ToList()` if you want this as a list.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with Linq and [`OfType<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netcore-3.1). The `where` clause ensures that the given type is a derivative of `LevelActor`, while `OfType<T>()` alone is not constrained and allows any type.

```
public List<T> GetActorsOfType<T>(List<LevelActor> list) where T : LevelActor
{
    return list.OfType<T>().ToList();
}
```

Then call it in your code like this to filter your list of `LevelActor` for instances with type `ExampleActor`.

```cs
var list = new List<LevelActor> { /* Your list of level actors */};
var filteredList = GetActorsOfType<ExampleActor>(list);
```